# Hide word randomly from a sentence

Tags: php, html

I have a sentence that I would like to hide a word randomly, for example:

```
<?php
$sentence = 'My name is Abu Rayane';
?>
```

How can I proceed to hide a word in that sentence and replace it with a input text, so the user can fill it and then check if it correct word or not? For example:

```
My name is Abu <input type="text" name="fillBlank"> <br />
<input type="submit" name="check" value="check">
```

Comment: `$removed_word = $words[array_rand($words)]; $words[array_rand($words)] = '___';`

Comment: this is returning "M"

Comment: Not sure how you're running it. It works for me: https://eval.in/185799

Comment: yes, I messed it up, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sentence = 'My name is Abu Rayane';
$sentence = explode(' ', $sentence); 
$position = rand(0, count($sentence) - 1);
$answer = $sentence[$position];
$sentence[$position] = '<input type="text" name="fillBlank">';
echo implode(" ", $sentence);
```

Example: https://eval.in/185829

Edit: make it work if the length of words in unknown

Comment: Beat me to it. Good answer.

Comment: @DanDoNet Thanks. `rand()` was the first thing I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like this

```
$word = explode(' ', $sentence);
$word = $word[rand(0, count($sentence) - 1)];
```

`explode` function is really useful if you want to break a string. There is also function `implode` which does the exact opposite

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, I got the answer from your diffenrent codes:

```
<?php
$sentence = 'My name is Abu Rayane';
$countSentence = str_word_count($sentence);

echo 'Total words '.$countSentence.'<br />';

// get random number from 0 to 4
$rand = rand(0, $countSentence - 1);

// explode sentence
$ex = explode(' ',$sentence);

// get the equivalent word for a rand number
$hide = $ex[$rand];

$z = implode(' ', $ex).'<br />';
echo str_replace($hide, '______', $z);
?>
```

Tested: https://eval.in/185847